# How to return a string from two object arrays?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to map through an object that has an array of objects in it. The wanted result would be the string with the specific key.

So example:

```
    // the keys
    const array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    
    const value = 'one';
    
    // in reality the keys have specific values based on the key
    const res = array1.map((key) => {
      return {
        [key]: value
      };
    });
    
    // the object that is used in the display
    const object1 = {
      a: 'somestring',
      b: 42,
      c: false,
      res,
    };
    
    // this first map is mandatory for the rest of the code
    Object.values(object1).map((object) => {
      // how to get the value from key="two"

     <Table>
     <TableCell>one</TableCell>
     </Table>
    });
```

So in more detail: I need the value from a key that has a specific value. So in this example, I want the value in res, where the key has value "two". And this value needs to be a string. I'm using typescript. So I inside the map I want to return a string: 'one'.
I need to return the string 'one' from the object that's key is 'two', in a tableCell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that what you exactly need. if it didn't help please comment below.

```
     // the keys
     const array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

     const value = 'one';

     // in reality the keys have specific values based on the key
     const res = array1.map((key) => {
       return {
         [key]: value
        };
     });
    // the object that is used in the display
    const object1 = {
      a: 'somestring',
      b: 42,
      c: false,
      res,
    };

    // this first map is mandatory for the rest of the code
    Object.values(object1).map((object) => {
      // how to get the value from key="two"
    
      if (typeof object === 'object') {
       console.log(object.filter(obj => obj.two)[0].two)
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives me the object, but I need only the string 'one' from this object.

Comment: Try this console.log(Object.values(object[1])[0])

Comment: I probably explained this really poorly, but the problem is I need to return the string 'one' from the object that's key is 'two', in a tableCell.

Comment: The last one just gives an error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: This works in the simple example, but I also just edited the wanted outcome, since this needs to be inside a tableCell and there this doesn't work since I can't use the if...